# Manipulating XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<library>
   <book>
      <title>Title</title>
      <author>author</author>
      <price>20</price>
   <book>
<library>
```

I want to be able to add a book and be able to change the price.

Does anybody have any incite on how to do this?

Everywhere were i look keeps referring to "simpleXML" however I can only figure out how to create the original file i cant seem to figure out how to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, i kinda agree that xml libraries documentation in PHP is not so intuitive to get going with.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml"); 

//add   
$book = $xml->addChild("book"); 
$book->addChild("title", "TTT"); 
$book->addChild("author", "AAA"); 
$book->addChild("price", 123); 

//edit 1st:
$xml->book[0]->price = "priceless";

//write result
$xml->asXML("result.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or [simplexml_load_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to read a file into an object you can work with.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($stringXML);
```

To add a value you could:

```
$simpleXML->addChild('Value', $value);
```

then to get a string back:

```
$stringXML = $simpleXML->asXML();
```

Comment: So lets say I have this saved in a file called test.XML 
I would say:...........................................................................                     
    $SimpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement( 'text.XML' );