# JavaScript vs PHP, manipulating XML value(text of an element) by URL(post)

Tags: php, javascript, xml, actionscript-3

Which is better and easier to use?
I have been trying to save and replace (if needed) some data in XML via php or js, like player's scores in a game (from an AS3 App).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scores>
  <game id="1">
    <slot top="1">
      <name>joe</name>
      <score>125688</score>
    </slot>
    <slot top="2">
      <name>john</name>
      <score>10943</score>
    </slot>
    <slot top="3">
      <name>yuri</name>
      <score>9235</score>
    </slot>
  </game>
</scores>
```

What is your advice to changing, for example, Yuri's score just by calling a url and posting some data from an AS3 app?

Comment: Proper method: DOM. Fugly-but-workable method: String manipulation. Beat-yourself-with-a-wet-noodle-until-dead: regexes

Answer (score 0):

Oops!
The JavaScript can't save XML files.
in this case we should use php, 
[manipulating-xml-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848589/manipulating-xml-with-php)